# Condition logic `or` in the influxDB filter function

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python, flux-influxdb

I have a flux query  that has several 'or' conditions in a filter function. It's something like this.

```
from(bucket: "my_buck")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_measurement")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["idDispositivo"] == "155" or r["idDispositivo"] == "150") 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

The example has only one 'or' but in the real query there can be several and the query would also be created dynamically. Is there a way to change

```
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["idDispositivo"] == "155" or r["idDispositivo"] == "150")
```

for something like

```
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["idDispositivo"] in ["155", "150"])
```

I know that this syntax is not correct, but ask if there is something similar that allows me to make the dynamic query easier without having to use so many 'or'

Note: I'm use the influxDB version 1.8

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [contains](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0/stdlib/universe/contains/) function in Flux that you could use. It will likely not perform as good as using `or` or regexp.

```js
from(bucket: "my_buck")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_measurement")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => contains(value: r["idDispositivo"], set: ["155", "150"]))
```

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work as well as using or? Is using or more efficient?

Comment: @RirroRomeu Maybe I'm wrong, but per https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/query-data/optimize-queries/#avoid-processing-filters-inline, I would guess that calling a function in the filter may prevent pushing it down to the datasource.